# iOS SDK - Implementation file in Objective C exposed during run time crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a public class A having a method toDo all written in objective c which is part of a SDK. I am able to invoke this method toDo from another project which i created. However when i try to do a command click on the method invocation from my project i can only see the header file of class A and not how toDo method is implemented in the .m file. But now i have forcefully embedded a crash in toDo and when i run my project again i see xcode showing up full details of the .m file of class A and where the crash is happening on runtime. This is exposing all the details of the .m file. How do i restrict this not showing up the details of .m file ? Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

you have to compose(compile) your A class into framework or library.
For your library you will provide .h file with interface of your classes.

Most likely you added your SDK as subproject, with all implementation details.

Comment: No the SDK is compiled with a .framework file and that i what i have included in my project and it contains only .h files.